# Article Logic Issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am working on a site that is built around articles and videos.  Additionally, members sign-up and create a profile.  Within that profile, there are "interests" that they can select in addition to some categories we place the user in based on other behavior.

My issue is that I am trying to create logic that will display articles and videos based upon three variables.  The variables are below.  What is the simplest way to do this?

1)  For members who have selected and "interest" I want to serve articles that have been tagged in the system as associated with that "interest" with the articles that have been most recently posted shown first.

2) For members who I don't have an interest for, but I have placed in a bucket based on behavior I want to serve articles that have been tagged in the system associated with that "bucket" with the articles that have been most recently posted shown first.

3)  If I don't have an "interest" or a "bucket" I just want articles to be served by most recently posted.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a follow up to my question, can I use contextual filters to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Profile module. This will allow you to customize the User Account Creation form and add in custom form fields [suchas term references]. This also will allow you to create relationships between each user and specific content. [Show all content of type X, which shares interests with the current user ID.]

https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2

I've used it and it's pretty awesome.